# Using ajax to pass time in seconds to div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to pass the time in seconds to the div with the div id of 'seconds', but for some reason it's not passing anything to the div. Please take a look at my code:

testing1.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function timeoutAjax(url,id,timeout) {

      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
           success:function(data) {
             document.getElementById( id ).innerHTML = data;
             setTimeout(function() { timeoutAjax(url,id,timeout); }, timeout);
           }

      });

}

timeoutAjax("testing2.php","seconds",1000);
<div id = "seconds"></div>

</script>
```

testing2.php

```
<?php

$date = date("s");
echo $date;

?>
```

Comment: isn't it because you miss < sign before ? in php opening tag? Also take this div outside the script tag.

Comment: @n-dru John Conde probably accidentally edited it out...

Comment: @n-dru About the div...why take it out of the script tag? Where should I put it?

Comment: The `<div id = "seconds"></div>` is also in the `<script>` tags?

Comment: @Varun Where should it be?

Comment: It should be in the `<body>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the div after closing script tag.

```
</script>
<div id = "seconds"></div>
```

Comment: If the ajax function returns the same exact data from before, does it still pass it to the div tag? Because I feel like that would waste a lot of data.

Comment: i assumed you are just testing how it works, seconds can be written by javascript alone

Comment: Yes. I am just testing how it works. I'm actually trying to retrieve data from my database. If the data retrieved is different from the last data retrieved, send it to the div, but if it's the same data, don't send it to the div, to save space. Is that doable?

Comment: then send in ajax data the innerHTML of div and let php check if it is the same - if not, echo the new value.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that, but if it doesn't echo anything, would it just echo null, and replace the previous data with nothing, and thus nothing will show up on the page?

Comment: if no echo, no success, so no replacing in div.

Comment: Just tested it. Yeah, it replace the previous data in the div with nothing. I actually want to keep the previous data if it's the same, without having to resend it to the div.

Comment: I did something like, if second is less than 30, echo it, but if not, don't echo it. It echo up to 30 seconds, and then showed up as blank for the last 30 seconds.